# iPhone gallery selected image location in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to call the api based on Image location (image taken location lat & long) from gallery. Can any one help me with proper guideline or sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can asset API and get the image location have a look at sample code below

https://gist.github.com/sumitlni/6421aece205ebefa647abe701d2429e0

```
// this code will be executed with in callback of 
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]).. 

let opts = PHFetchOptions()
            opts.fetchLimit = 1
            let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [URL], options: opts)
for assetIndex in 0..<assets.count {
let asset = assets[assetIndex]
                // print("Location: \(asset.location?.description) Taken: \(asset.creationDate)")
location = String(describing: asset.location!)
// Here you have the location if it found 
}
```